# Which Spanish words are most commonly used to describe smells?

Tags: selección-de-palabras, vocabulario

I would like to know how to name different smells in Spanish. In English, for example, we have adjectives like smelly, fishy, sweet, disgusting, stinky, rotten,etc (actually mainly for bad smells).

How do Spanish speakers, particularly those from Latin America do this for pleasant and unpleasant smells?

Comment: Welcome to our site! We're glad you're here.  Unfortunately, your question as it's worded is really too broad to fit our format here. We're looking for specific, answerable questions. Your question could, quite literally, have an indefinite number of correct answers, as it's always possible to apply a new word in a creative way to apply to smells. You might consider narrowing the focus of your question so that we can re-open it.

Answer (score 1):

Well, first of all, this could be an issue where you'll find quite a few differences among countries, or even regions inside a same country.

The words I know for what you are looking for are:

- Pleasant smells:

  - "Oloroso"
- Unpleasant smells:

  - "Hediondo"
  - "Maloliente"
  - "Apestoso"